# unable to add new rows in an excel file using xlsx module in perl

Tags: excel, perl, xlsx

i am trying to append new rows in an excel file, only the last data is present , since it overwrites any previous data written , in this code i have a for loop that loops again to write the same data in a second row but , instead it rewrites the existing data

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Excel::Writer::XLSX;

my $workbook    = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new( 'ke.xlsx' );#create the excel

my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet(); 

my $server= "se";
my $domain  = "de";
my $backup = "b";



# Some sample data for the table.
my $data = [[ $server, $domain ,$backup],
   ];
$worksheet->set_column( 'A:G', 20 );

for(my $i = 0 ;$i<2;$i++){
     $worksheet->add_table(   # Add a table to the worksheet.
    'A1:G8',
    {
       data      => $data,
        total_row => 1,
        columns   => [
            { 

                header => 'server name', 
            },

            {
                header         => 'Domain Name',


            },
            {
                header         => 'Back Up address',


            }
        ]
    }
);

}
```

Comment: If you are looking for help with debugging code see https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: I am not looking for someone to debug my code, i want to know  whether there is a functionality that i can use @Yunnosch

Comment: Edit your question, it is hard to read and currently seems (to me) to describe a problem which you have with the given code. The question whether this code would do what you want can be answered by trying it, can't it?

Answer (score 0):

Your code writes the table at `A1:G8` each time. You need to change that if you want the tables in different places.

Comment: It doesn't work even if i use 'A:G' or 'A2:G8' for the successive one.

Comment: @kewin: Presumably you'll need to move the coordinates by at least the size of the table. It won't automatically put the new data out of the way of any existing contents.

Comment: :how can i increment the size

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work for me using sample data:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Excel::Writer::XLSX;

my $workbook = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new('ke.xlsx' );#create the excel

my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet(); 

#my $server= "se";
#my $domain  = "de";
#my $backup = "b";

# Some sample data for the table.
#my $data = [[ $server, $domain ,$backup],
#   ];

my $data = [ ["se", "de","b"],
             ["ll", "pp","t"],
             ["yu", "ar","e"],
             ["gt", "po","w"],
             ["br", "tp","g"] ];
$worksheet->set_column( 'A:G', 20 );

for(my $i = 0 ;$i<2;$i++){
     $worksheet->add_table(   # Add a table to the worksheet.
    'A1:G8',
    {
       data      => $data,
        total_row => 1,
        columns   => [
            { 
                header => 'server name', 
            },

            {
                header => 'Domain Name',
            },
            {
                header => 'Back Up address',
            }
        ]
    }
);

}
```

[image]

Comment: no you got me wrong, the $data is not provided beforehand i have an outer loop which i have not included ,that basically gets the design information and stores it again in the $data,  the for loop which adds table should append the $data in the next line , i should not include it beforehand in the $data variable .    The my $data = [[ $server, $domain ,$backup],
   ]; should remain the same , i am trying to automate not add manually.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on this module, however we did not used add_table instead we used $worksheet->write_row.
I think you should try writing your data using write_row
https://metacpan.org/pod/Excel::Writer::XLSX

If you don't want to use write_row, then for more examples on add_table please visit : https://metacpan.org/pod/Excel::Writer::XLSX#TABLES-IN-EXCEL

Hope that helps :)